# Receive any notify when call undefined function in lua

Tags: function, lua, undefined-symbol

In C++ code:

```cpp
class CWindowUI {
  public CWindowUI(const char* title,int width,int height);
  .....
};

static int CreateWindow(lua_State *l)
{
    int          width,height;
    char        *title;
    CWindowUI  **winp, *win;

    name = (char *) luaL_checkstring(l, 1);
    width= lua_tounsigned(l, 2);
    height= lua_tounsigned(l, 3);

    win = new CWindowUI(title,width,height);
    if (win == NULL) {
        lua_pushboolean(l, 0);
        return 1;
    }

    winp = (CWindowUI **) lua_newuserdata(l, sizeof(CWindowUI *));
    luaL_getmetatable(l, "WindowUI");
    lua_setmetatable(l, -2);
    *winp = win;

    return 1;
}
```

In Lua code:

```
local win = CreateWindow("title", 480, 320);
win:resize(800, 600);
```

Now my question is:

Function `CreateWindow` will return a object named `win` and the function `resize` is     not defined. How do I get a notification when I call an undefined function in Lua?

The notification shall include the string `"resize"` and the arguments `800,600`.
I want to modify the source to map the undefined function onto the callback function but it is incorrect .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get a notification when I call an undefined function in lua.

You don't. Not in the way that you mean it.

You can hook [an `__index` metamethod](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8) onto your registered "WindowUI" metatable (*groan*). Your metamethod will only get the userdata it was called on and the key that was used.

But you cannot differentiate between a function call and simply accessing a member variable, since *Lua* doesn't differentiate between these. If you return a function from your metamethod, and the user invokes the function-call operator on the return from the metamethod, then it will be called. Otherwise, they get a function to play with as they see fit. They can store it, pass it around, call it later, whatever. It's a value, like any other.

Comment: when compile the *.lua file,lua use the hash to map the C function to lua function like "__index",so i want to modify the part of the hash that can map the undefined function to the default function,so i can set the default function to get it.

Comment: what do you mean with "compile the *.lua"? lua code is not compiled, but interpreted / executed. the evaluation of the expression / call "win:resize(800, 600)" takes place at the time, the code execution reaches this point.

Comment: @tfzxyinhao: "*lua use the hash to map the C function to lua function like "__index"*" No. You're thinking *way* too low-level. Don't think of "hashes" and so forth. There are tables, keys that map to values. How that's implemented is irrelevant. What matters is that, when Lua attempts to access a userdata as though it were a table, it will call the `__index` metamethod for that userdata. It is *your* job to return the proper function for Lua to call. Period. No hashes, no notifications; just return a function.